# Maven | How can I use build-helper-maven-plugin in Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle, build

I'm trying to migrate a project from Maven to Gradle where I'm using the maven plugin **build-helper-maven-plugin**. I reviewed the documentation on [this site](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html) where it showed how to add this to my Gradle dependencies, but there is no information on how to configure it.

Here's a sample of my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-generated-source</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${path1}/${path2}</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I intend to configure the source path in gradle, however, the documentation only listed how to import the dependency, like so:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0'
```

In case this is not possible to accomplish in Gradle is there an alternative to this plug in I can use?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, gradle uses a slightly different model internally, so you can actually get it quite easily. Gradle use a definition of source sets for a given configuration. So there is a source set for main/java, where you can add more directories to. The sourcesets are used by the compiler et al.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java'
            srcDirs "${path1}/${path2}"
        }
    }
 }
```

There may be additional help in the documentation, but it is sometimes hard to comprehend. https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html